# Delphi Onvif SOAP Calls

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl, ip-camera, onvif

I'd like to get started using Delphi to access and control IP-cameras with the Onvif SOAP protocol.

However, I do not understand how to actually perform the calls from Delphi.
I've imported the following WDSL:

http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl

and a unit was generated in Delphi. But how do I perform the calls towards the camera? Am I supposed to use this generated together with THTTPRIO somehow? How to I specify the IP-address of the camera I have (currently an Axis Q1755 camera).

If someone could get me started by pointing me in the correct direction I would be very grateful.

Comment: To specifiy the P address: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596868/onvif-how-to-form-the-device-web-service-address-from-the-ip-address-of-an-nvt

Answer (score 1):

If you used Delphi's `WSDL` importer it will have generated the necessary classes to represent any `request` fro the `SOAP` webservice and its corresponding `response`.

It will also have generated a `wrapper`, which is what you will use to actually do the calls. Usually it will have a few methods like following:

```
function mySoapMethod(myRequest: TmyRequestType): TMyResponse;
```

To do a call you basically do following:

1. Get a `wrapper` instance reference. There should be a method in the unit called something similar to `GetWrapper`.
2. If necessary, you create an instance for the `request type` and set all its properties. Mind you, it may be there is no request class as such if the `SOAP` method just needs a few basic types as parameters. Take also in account that any sufficiently complicated `request type` might implicate that you will need to create instances of objects and  assign them as properties to the request.
3. Use the corresponding `wrapper method` to send the request (or setthe parameters if it is a simple call).
4. Receive the `response` object and act on it as needed.

In pseudocode it would be as following:

```
myWrapper := GetMyWrapper();
myRequest := TMyRequest.Create;
//set myRequest properties
myResponse := myWrapper.mySoapMethod(myRequest);
//do whatever you need with the response
```

**About the wrapper**

The `wrapper` will be an implementation of the `IInvokable` interface with some added methods. Actually it should have one method for each `SOAP method` you can call.

Usually its interface declaration will be something like this:

```
TmyWrapper = interface(IInvokable)
['...'] //GUID here
  function oneMethod(...): oneMethodResponse;
  function anotherMethod(...): anotherMethodResponse;
end;

function getMyWrapper(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): TmyWrapper ;
```

And the function's implementation will look like this:

```
function GetMyWrapper(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): TmyWrapper;
const
  defWSDL = 'http://<soap service IP and port>/<soap service name>?wsdl';
  defURL  = 'http://<soap service IP and port>/<soap service name>';
  defSvc  = '<default service name>';
  defPrt  = '<default service port>';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as TmyWrapper );
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

Some side notes:

- You can inject an `HTTPRIO` instance to the `wrapper` when you get its instance by using the `getXYZWrapper` method. This can help you for example to set another `SOAP URL` or to inspect the `XML` generated.
- Sometimes Delphi generates the `XML` to be sent in a slightly different way as the `SOAP` expects it. If you think it should work but does not, inspect the `XML` generated and compare it to what it should be. You can use the `HTTPRIO` object's `onBeforeExecute` event to modify the `XML`before sending it.
- I you need it, you can also use the `onAfterExecute` method of the `HTTPRIO` object to inspect the `XML` response.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Unfortunately, I have no Wrapper function in the generated unit that looks like the one you suggested. I have a bunch of TRemotable classes and some enums and Interfaces. But how do I wire these up with the HTTPRIO object to call my camera?

Comment: @TomRay74, sorry, it was late yesterday and I wrote this answer out of my head. I'll update it to give more detail on the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

you can use my imported WSDLs by Delphi XE7

Media :
[Media.WSDL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aFAstwRqJdyo-OxktHsRnssbvFByblvU/view?usp=sharing)

Imaging :
[Imaging.wsdl](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PdNih7iC5ODVhOcsb0ps8m0UPZAauBLq/view?usp=sharing)

device management:
[devicemgmt.wsdl](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bRKbw7nfR7vxYJwQJJQ1YDczqNzuE8K7/view?usp=sharing)

---

usually imported WSDLs have a function such as

```
function GetMySoap(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): MySoap;
```

but it not exists in onvif imported wsdl.

add this function to your project instance, Media2 is name of IInvokable class

```
function GetWSSoap(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): Media2;
const
  defWSDL = 'http://192.168.1.1/onvif/Media?WSDL';
  defURL  = 'http://192.168.1.1/onvif/Media';
  defSvc  = 'Media';
  defPrt  = '80';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as Media2);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

another Solution , get some general information with send a http requst 
Sample request 
GetProfiles is name of methods

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">
<soap:Header>
<Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1"> 
<UsernameToken> 
<Username>%s</Username> 
<Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">%s</Password> 
<Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">%s</Nonce> 
<Created xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">%s</Created> 
</UsernameToken> 
</Security> 
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<GetProfiles xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl" /> 
</soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

button Code :

ip : http://192.168.1.1

url : onvif/media

```
  GetONVIFPasswordDigest(ed_user.text, ED_pass.text, PasswordDigest, Nonce, Created);
  User_Pass := Format(M_Request, [UserName, PasswordDigest, Nonce, Created]);
  ONVIFRequest(ED_IP.Text + ED_URL.Text,User_Pass,Result);
```

password maker Procedures :

```
procedure GetONVIFPasswordDigest(const UserName, Password: String; Var PasswordDigest, Nonce, Created: String);
Var
  i: Integer;
  raw_nonce, bnonce, digest , S_In: TBytes;
  raw_digest: TBytes;
  DT : TDateTime;
begin
  SetLength(raw_nonce, 20);
  for i := 0 to High(raw_nonce) do
    raw_nonce[i] := Random(256);
  bnonce := TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(raw_nonce);
  Nonce := BytesToString(bnonce);
  DT := Now();
  Created := GetONVIFDateTime(DT);
  S_In := raw_nonce + StringToBytes(Created) + StringToBytes(Password);
  raw_digest := SHA1(S_In);
  digest := TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(raw_digest);
  PasswordDigest := BytesToString(digest);
end;
```

get data procedure :

```
procedure ONVIFRequest(const Addr: String; const InStream, OutStream: TStringStream);overload;
Var
  idhtp1: TIdHTTP;
  Uri: TIdURI;
begin
  idhtp1 := TIdHTTP.Create;
  Uri := TIdURI.Create(Addr);
  try
    With idhtp1 do
    begin
      AllowCookies := True;
      HandleRedirects := True;
      Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
      Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
      Request.Host := '';
      Request.Connection := '';
      Request.Accept := '';
      Request.UserAgent := '';

      Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
      Request.ContentType := 'text/xml;charset=utf-8';
      Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Host: ' + Uri.Host);
      //-------------------
      request.username := ed_user.text;
      request.password := ed_pass.text;
      HTTPOptions := [hoInProcessAuth,hoForceEncodeParams,hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
      //-------------------

      ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
      Post(Addr, InStream, OutStream);
    end;
  finally
    Uri.Free;
    idhtp1.Free;
  end;
end;
procedure ONVIFRequest(const Addr, Request: String; Var Answer: String);overload;
Var
  InStream, OutStream: TStringStream;
begin
  InStream := TStringStream.Create(Request);
  OutStream := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    ONVIFRequest(Addr, InStream, OutStream);
    Answer := OutStream.DataString;
  finally
    InStream.Free;
    OutStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You can also find a better sample here

```
https://github.com/Laex/Delphi-ONVIF
```